# Error: number of rows of matrices must match (ggplot facet)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to assign labels to my ggplot2 facets. As I'm thinking this is a character problem, I'm using the labels exactly as they are in my dataset, so it's a little long, I apologize.

```
set.seed(123)

names <- c("acquisitionsmergers", "analystratings", "assets", "balanceofpayments", 
"bankruptcy", "civilunrest", "corporateresponsibility", "credit", 
"creditratings", "crime", "dividends", "earnings", "equityactions", 
"exploration", "government", "indexes", "industrialaccidents", 
"insidertrading", "investorrelations", "laborissues", "legal", 
"marketing", "orderimbalances", "partnerships", "pricetargets", 
"productsservices", "publicopinion", "regulatory", "revenues", 
"security", "stockprices", "taxes", "technicalanalysis", "transportation", 
"warconflict")

mylabels <- c("acquisitionsmergers" = "Acquisitions/Mergers",
                   "analystratings" = "Analyst Ratings",
                   "assets" = "Assets",
                   "balanceofpayments" = "Balance of Payments",
                   "bankruptcy" = "Bankruptcy",
                   "civilunrest" = "Civil Unrest",
                   "corporateresponsibility" = "Corporate Responsibility",
                   "credit" = "Credit",
                   "creditratings" = "Credit Ratings",
                   "crime" = "Crime",
                   "dividends" = "Dividends",
                   "earnings" = "Earnings",
                   "equityactions" = "Equity Actions",
                   "exploration" = "Exploration",
                   "government" = "Government",
                   "indexes" = "Indexes",
                   "industrialaccidents" = "Industrial Accidents",
                   "insidertrading" = "Insider Trading",
                   "investorrelations" = "Investor Relations",
                   "laborissues" = "Labor Issues",
                   "legal" = "Legal",
                   "marketing" = "Marketing",
                   "orderimbalances" = "Order Imbalances",
                   "partnerships" = "Partnerships",
                   "pricetargets" = "Price Targets",
                   "productsservices" = "Product Services",
                   "publicopinion" = "Public Opinion",
                   "regulatory" = "Regulatory",
                   "revenues" = "Revenues",
                   "security" = "Security",
                   "stockprices" = "Stockprices",
                   "taxes" = "Taxes",
                   "technicalanalysis" = "Technical Analysis",
                   "transportation" = "Transportation",
                   "warconflict" = "War Conflict")

df <- data.frame(item = rep(names, each=5), value=rnorm(5*35,5,2), date = rep(seq(as.Date("2000/1/1"), by = "month", length.out = 5),35))
```

Then,

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x=date, y=value, color=item)) +
  geom_line() + 
  facet_wrap( ~ item, ncol=4, scales="free_y", labeller = mylabels)
```

Produces

```
Error in cbind(labels = list(), list(`{`, if (!is.null(.rows) || !is.null(.cols)) { : 
  number of rows of matrices must match (see arg 2)
```

I've used labeller before without problems, so I'm not sure why it's throwing this error. I checked a few things, such as making sure there is a match:

```
all(names(mylabels) %in% names)
length(mylabels) == length(names)
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about this?

```
df$item <-  factor(df$item, 
                   labels = c("Acquisitions/Mergers","Analyst Ratings","Assets", "Balance of Payments","Bankruptcy", "Civil Unrest",
                              "Corporate Responsibility", "Credit", "Credit Ratings", "Crime", "Dividends", "Earnings", "Equity Actions",
                              "Exploration", "Government", "Indexes", "Industrial Accidents", "Insider Trading", "Investor Relations",
                              "Labor Issues", "Legal",  "Marketing", "Order Imbalances","Partnerships",  "Price Targets",
                              "Product Services",  "Public Opinion","Regulatory",  "Revenues","Security", "Stockprices",
                              "Taxes",  "Technical Analysis",  "Transportation", "War Conflict"))

ggplot(df, aes(x=date, y=value, color=item)) +
  geom_line() + 
  facet_wrap( ~ item, ncol=4, scales="free_y")
```

**UPDATE**

to address the questions in the comment

***First***, are the label factors taken as the unique order? In other words, the original "item" vector in the dataframe should be sorted so it is in the same order as labels?

**Answer**

The order of levels in the `labels` vector must be the same as the order of levels in `item` vector.

Below are the levels of `item`

```
levels(df$item)
 [1] "acquisitionsmergers"     "analystratings"          "assets"                  "balanceofpayments"       "bankruptcy"             
 [6] "civilunrest"             "corporateresponsibility" "credit"                  "creditratings"           "crime"                  
[11] "dividends"               "earnings"                "equityactions"           "exploration"             "government"             
[16] "indexes"                 "industrialaccidents"     "insidertrading"          "investorrelations"       "laborissues"            
[21] "legal"                   "marketing"               "orderimbalances"         "partnerships"            "pricetargets"           
[26] "productsservices"        "publicopinion"           "regulatory"              "revenues"                "security"               
[31] "stockprices"             "taxes"                   "technicalanalysis"       "transportation"          "warconflict"
```

I usually copy paste them inside `labels` add commas, remove the numbers and change the names as I like.

There is another way, below, to change the names of the levels of `item` using `dplyr` and `forcats`

```
library(dplyr)
library(forcats)
df <- df %>% 
  mutate(item_update = item) %>%  # create new column called item_update to change the names of item levels
  mutate(item_update = fct_recode(item_update,
                                  "Acquisitions/Mergers" = "acquisitionsmergers" ,
                                  "Analyst Ratings" = "analystratings" ,
                                  "Assets" =  "assets",
                                  "Balance of Payments"  = "balanceofpayments",
                                  "Bankruptcy" = "bankruptcy",
                                  "Civil Unrest" = "civilunrest",
                                  "Corporate Responsibility" = "corporateresponsibility",
                                  "Credit" = "credit",
                                  "Credit Ratings" = "creditratings",
                                  "Crime" = "crime",
                                  "Dividends" = "dividends",
                                  "Earnings" = "earnings",
                                  "Equity Actions" = "equityactions",
                                  "Exploration" = "exploration",
                                  "Government" = "government",
                                  "Indexes" = "indexes",
                                  "Industrial Accidents" = "industrialaccidents",
                                  "Insider Trading" = "insidertrading",
                                  "Investor Relations" = "investorrelations",
                                  "Labor Issues" = "laborissues",
                                  "Legal" = "legal" ,
                                  "Marketing" = "marketing",
                                  "Order Imbalances" = "orderimbalances",
                                  "Partnerships" = "partnerships",
                                  "Price Targets" = "pricetargets",
                                  "Product Services" = "productsservices",
                                  "Public Opinion" = "publicopinion" ,
                                  "Regulatory" = "regulatory",
                                  "Revenues" = "revenues",
                                  "Security" = "security",
                                  "Stockprices" = "stockprices",
                                  "Taxes" = "taxes",
                                  "Technical Analysis" = "technicalanalysis",
                                  "Transportation" = "transportation" ,
                                  "War Conflict" = "warconflict"
                                  ))
```

and we can plot it as below

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=date, y=value, color=item)) +
  geom_line() + 
  facet_wrap( ~ item_update, ncol=4, scales="free_y")
```

***Second***, does this appear to be a bug, which I should file with the ggplot2 page?

**Answer**

It is not a bug. 
Your approach will work fine if you edit `mylabels` to be

```
mylabels <- c(acquisitionsmergers = "Acquisitions/Mergers",
              analystratings = "Analyst Ratings",
              assets = "Assets",
              balanceofpayments = "Balance of Payments",
              bankruptcy = "Bankruptcy",
              civilunrest = "Civil Unrest",
              corporateresponsibility = "Corporate Responsibility",
              credit = "Credit",
              creditratings = "Credit Ratings",
              crime = "Crime",
              dividends = "Dividends",
              earnings = "Earnings",
              equityactions = "Equity Actions",
              exploration = "Exploration",
              government = "Government",
              indexes = "Indexes",
              industrialaccidents = "Industrial Accidents",
              insidertrading = "Insider Trading",
              investorrelations = "Investor Relations",
              laborissues = "Labor Issues",
              legal = "Legal",
              marketing = "Marketing",
              orderimbalances = "Order Imbalances",
              partnerships = "Partnerships",
              pricetargets = "Price Targets",
              productsservices = "Product Services",
              publicopinion = "Public Opinion",
              regulatory = "Regulatory",
              revenues = "Revenues",
              security = "Security",
              stockprices = "Stockprices",
              taxes = "Taxes",
              technicalanalysis = "Technical Analysis",
              transportation = "Transportation",
              warconflict = "War Conflict")
```

and the plot to be

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=date, y=value, color=item)) +
  geom_line() + 
  facet_wrap( ~ item, ncol=4, scales="free_y", labeller = labeller(item = mylabels))
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks! A few things: First, are the label factors taken as the unique order? In other words, the original "item" vector in the dataframe should be sorted so it is in the same order as labels? Second, does this appear to be a bug, which I should file with the ggplot2 page?